# Cordova upgrade and new plugin removed my index.html and css file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I did a cordova version upgrade and installed push notification plugin to my project, but after installing I find all my project is gone! It restored back to default cordova hello interface! Is there a way to find my project back? I'm so stressed now

Comment: At the time of plugin installation, cordova copies www directory from outer most directory to platform's www directory. To overcome this issue place platform's www directory into outer most directory.

Comment: Read the docs before coding: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#www

Comment: But is there any ways to find my project files anymore?